# Bokeh - unable to update ColumnDataSource upon change in dropdown menu

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm having issues with updating an underlying ColumnDataSource when selecting a new value from a dropdown. In the "update_data" section, I am changing the values of the underlying ColumnDataSource for my plot.  The error bars get updated on the plot, but the plotted data does not change.  I've simplified the code below.  Any idea how to update all of the data, and not just the error bars?

```
from bokeh.layouts import row, column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models.widgets import Dropdown
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.models import (
    ColumnDataSource,
    HoverTool,
    LinearColorMapper,
    BasicTicker,
    PrintfTickFormatter,
    ColorBar,
    Legend,
    Whisker,
)
from bokeh.models.widgets import PreText, Select, RadioGroup, TextInput
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import dodge, factor_cmap
import bokeh.plotting
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
import io
import base64
import random
import statistics as stat
from bokeh.models.tickers import SingleIntervalTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show




def sectionize(df, rows, cols):
    rowWise = df.stack()
    colWise = df.transpose().stack()
    rowData = []
    colData = []
    for x in rows:
        rowData.append(list(rowWise[x]))
    for x in range(1, (cols + 1)):
        colData.append(list(colWise[x]))
    print("sectionize has occured")
    return rowData, colData

def getLowerUpper(data):
    lower, upper = [], []
    for x in data:
        if x:
            mean = stat.mean(x)
            std = stat.stdev(x)
            lower.append(mean - std)
            upper.append(mean + std)
        else:
            lower.append(0)
            upper.append(0)
    return lower, upper

def sectionizePlot(source, source_error, type, base):
    print("sectionize plot created with typ: " + type)
    colors = []
    for x in range(0, len(base)):
        colors.append(getRandomColor())
    title = type + "-wise Intensity Distribution"
    p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, title=title)
    p.add_layout(
        Whisker(source=source_error, base="base", upper="upper", lower="lower"))
    for i, sec in enumerate(source.data['base']):
        p.circle(x=source_error.data["base"][i], y=sec, color=colors[i])
    p.xaxis.axis_label = type
    p.yaxis.axis_label = "Intensity"
    if (type.split()[-1] == "Row"):
        print("hit a row")
        conv = dict(enumerate(list("nABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP")))
        conv.pop(0)
        p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = conv
    p.xaxis.ticker = SingleIntervalTicker(interval=1)
    print("sectionizePlot changed")
    return p

def getRandomColor():
    colors = ['aqua', 'aquamarine', 'black', 'blue', 'blueviolet', 'brown', 'burlywood', 'cadetblue', 'chartreuse', 'chocolate',
         'coral', 'cornflowerblue', 'crimson', 'cyan', 'darkblue', 'darkcyan', 'darkgoldenrod', 'darkgray', 'darkgreen',
         'darkgrey', 'darkkhaki', 'darkmagenta', 'darkolivegreen', 'darkorange', 'darkorchid', 'darkred', 'darksalmon',
         'darkseagreen', 'darkslateblue', 'darkslategray', 'darkslategrey', 'darkturquoise', 'darkviolet', 'deeppink',
         'deepskyblue', 'dimgray', 'dimgrey', 'dodgerblue', 'firebrick', 'forestgreen', 'fuchsia', 'gold', 'goldenrod',
         'gray', 'green', 'greenyellow', 'grey', 'hotpink', 'indianred', 'indigo', 'khaki', 'lavender', 'lawngreen', 'lime',
         'limegreen', 'magenta', 'maroon', 'mediumaquamarine', 'mediumblue', 'mediumorchid', 'mediumpurple',
         'mediumseagreen', 'mediumslateblue', 'mediumspringgreen', 'mediumturquoise', 'mediumvioletred', 'midnightblue',
         'navy', 'olive', 'olivedrab', 'orange', 'orangered', 'orchid', 'peachpuff', 'peru', 'pink', 'plum', 'powderblue',
         'purple', 'red', 'rosybrown', 'royalblue', 'saddlebrown', 'salmon', 'sandybrown', 'seagreen', 'sienna', 'silver',
         'skyblue', 'slateblue', 'slategray', 'slategrey', 'springgreen', 'steelblue', 'tan', 'teal', 'thistle', 'tomato',
              'turquoise', 'violet', 'yellow', 'yellowgreen']
    return colors[random.randint(0, 101)]


colBase = list(range(1, 3))
colData = [[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]
colData_lower, colData_upper = getLowerUpper(colData)
colSectTotSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=[]))
colSectTotSource_error = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=[], lower=[], upper=[]))
colSectTotSource.data = dict(base=colData)
colSectTotSource_error.data = dict(base=colBase, lower=colData_lower, upper=colData_upper)

menu = [("A", "A"), ("B", "B")]
dropdown = Dropdown(label="Dropdown button", button_type="warning", menu=menu)
colPlot = sectionizePlot(colSectTotSource, colSectTotSource_error, "Column", colBase)

def update_data(attrname, old, new):
    d = dropdown.value
    if(d == "B"):
        colData = [[11,12,13,14,15,16], [17,18,19,20,21,22]]
    else:
        colData = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

    colData_lower, colData_upper = getLowerUpper(colData)
    #colSectTotSource = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(base=[]))
    colSectTotSource.data = dict(base=colData)
    colSectTotSource_error.data = dict(base=colBase, lower=colData_lower, upper=colData_upper)

for w in [dropdown]:
    w.on_change('value', update_data)

inputs = column(dropdown)
curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, colPlot, width=800))
```

Answer (score 0):

The circles are not updating because you are not actually configuring the call to circle to use the source:

```
p.circle(x=source_error.data["base"][i], y=sec, color=colors[i])
```

When you pass actual lists/arrays as `x`, `y`, etc, as you are doing above, then Bokeh creates a new CDS to use internally. If you want a glyph to utilize a source you pass in, you actually have to pass it in, and the coordinates should only refer to the column names of that source:

```
my_source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(foo=[...], bar=[...]))
p.circle(x="foo", y="bar", source=my_source)
```

Additionally, the format of data in your CDS is not correct for this usage:

```
{'base': [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]}
```

As the name suggests, the ColumnDataSource contains *columns*. The value of each column needs to be a *one-dimensional* array or list, not a list of lists as you have here (a handful of "multi"-glyphs accept this, but not circle, etc). I.e. you will need to have a separate column for every circle, not one column with "sublists" for each circle.